# Magento 2.2.5: Adding cart-attribute for cart-rules / conditions tab

Tags: product-attribute, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento-2.2.5

I use a product attribute called "carton" which describes in how many carton a product is packed. I want to add a cart-rule which counts the amount of all cartons in the cart (accordingly the amount entered for each product in carton product-attribute).

According the total amount of cartons i want to offer special discount.

The function is similar to the weight function which also make a sum of all weight in the cart.

Your help would be really appreciated!
Thank you

[image: View of conditions]